# MySQL: Return only last message in flat/conversation message table

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm writing a messaging system like Facebook's new Messages system, where the entire back and forth between two users is considered one conversation.  (As opposed to traditional email where each reply is a separate message or gMail's conversations where replies are all together in a conversation but you can still have multiple conversations between people).  MySQL version is 5.0.92.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to write the query for the "inbox" type view.  All I would need is the very last message between two people, which [would be easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811750/get-the-last-entries-using-group-by) except I don't know how to take into account both the "from_id" and "to_id" fileds.

My messages table looks like this:
[image: messages table]

The highlighted rows are the ones I'd like returned (#2 wouldn't be returned because the last message between users 42 and 43 is #8, for instance).  Is it possible to do this?  Or would I be better off using two queries (one for to_id and one for from_id) then working them out in PHP?

Thanks for your help

SQL to replicate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `message_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `to_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message_sent` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message_body` text NOT NULL,
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT '0 = no, 1 = yes',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`message_id`),
  KEY `to` (`to_id`),
  KEY `is_read` (`is_read`),
  KEY `sent` (`message_sent`),
  KEY `from` (`from_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `messages` (`message_id`, `to_id`, `from_id`, `message_sent`, `message_body`, `is_read`) VALUES
(1, 42, 43, '2011-04-01 11:54:05', 'message 1', 0),
(2, 43, 42, '2011-04-01 11:54:05', 'message 1.2', 0),
(3, 42, 44, '2011-04-01 11:55:05', 'message 2', 1),
(4, 44, 42, '2011-04-01 11:55:02', 'message 2.1', 0),
(5, 43, 44, '2011-04-01 15:05:42', 'Message 3', 0),
(6, 44, 43, '2011-04-01 15:05:58', 'Message 3.1', 0),
(7, 42, 43, '2011-04-02 11:54:05', 'message x', 0),
(8, 43, 42, '2011-04-02 11:54:05', 'message x.2', 0);
```

Edit: for those interested:

```
select `m`.`message_id` AS `message_id`,`m`.`to_id` AS `to_id`,`ut`.`name` AS `to_name`,`m`.`from_id` AS `from_id`,`uf`.`name` AS `from_name`,`m`.`message_sent` AS `message_sent`,`m`.`message_body` AS `message_body`,`m`.`is_read` AS `is_read` from ((`messages` `m` join `users` `ut` on((`m`.`to_id` = `ut`.`id`))) join `users` `uf` on((`m`.`from_id` = `uf`.`id`))) where `m`.`message_id` in (select max(`messages`.`message_id`) AS `MAX(message_id)` from `messages` group by greatest(`messages`.`to_id`,`messages`.`from_id`),least(`messages`.`to_id`,`messages`.`from_id`));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(message_id) FROM messages GROUP BY GREATEST(to_id, from_id), LEAST(to_id, from_id);
```

If you want the messages themselves you can put this in a subselect, or turn it into a view and join it with messages.

Comment: I think this may be the answer I was looking for, let me play with it a bit.  Thanks Neil!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from messageTable 
where message_id in 
(select max(message_id) from messageTable where from_id = yourFromId and to_id = yourToId)
```

Updated

```
select * 
from messageTable 
where (message_id in 
       (select max(message_id) from messageTable where from_id = yourFromId and to_id = yourToId))
    or (message_id in 
       (select max(message_id) from messageTable where from_id = yourToId and to_id = yourFromId)))
```

Comment: Thanks John -- that's not quite what I'm after, since that would limit it to one side of a conversation with one person

Comment: Correct...this would return the last message_id that matches the from_id and to_id.

Comment: I still don't quite think that's what I'm going for, since from_id and to_id are in both subqueries.  I'm looking for the last entry _either way_.  So: SELECT max(m.message_id) AS id, m.to_id, m.from_id, m.message_sent, m.message_body, m.is_read, m.message_id FROM   messages m  WHERE (m.to_id = 42) GROUP BY  m.from_id ORDER BY id DESC;  then a corresponding  subquery using where m.from_id = 42, but then what?