# MYSQL Query that selects last message between you and other people from table like the facebook one

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the last message between me(given the id) and other people just like the facebook one
:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wejCk.png
![first ss][1]

while having this 'messages' table structure :
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHFJq.png
![second ss][2]

I dont know how to explain it but the query should return me the latest messages after checking if my id is in id_from or id_to and order by either date DESC or id DESC (same thing) and leaving only the messages with unique people ( it can return a message you sent to someone if its the last one in the convo between you and him )

I've searched for this online but I cant seem to find an answer so this is my last resort

I have this query (in php):
"SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from_id='$id' OR to_id='$id' ORDER BY id DESC"
but this returns all the messages between me and other people, not the last one with each unique user

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Return only last message in flat/conversation message table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518195/mysql-return-only-last-message-in-flat-conversation-message-table)

Comment: As the link @Solomon provided suggests, you will likely need max(id) or max(date).

Comment: i couldnt understand the query in the link to adapt it to my situation , also max(something) wont work for me , not in php and nor in phpmyadmin console idk why mods are too fast to close threads