# Cannot get last item from table with mysql group by

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to make a mysql query that receives the last item in a group by clause. However, when I group by, it gives me the first record. I tried many joins, and many searches, but cannot find the right way to go about it.

My database is designed like so:

messages:

- message_id *
- thread_id
- user_id
- message
- created_at

users:

- user_id*
- name

threads:

- thread_id*
- name

usersthreads:

- id*
- user_id
- thread_id

The query I am trying to make should be, provided a user_id,:

- threads.thread_id
- users.name
- messages.message
- messages.created_at

The catch here is this, for users.name, I need not the provided user's name, but the other user's name that is in the thread. My current stab at it right now stands as this:

```
select t.thread_id as thread, t.name as name, messages.message as message,        max(messages.created_at) as date  
from (SELECT threads.thread_id, nt.name
      FROM threads,messages,
            (SELECT users.name as name, usersthreads.thread_id as threadID
            from users,usersthreads
            where users.user_id=usersthreads.user_id
            and users.user_id!='$userID') as nt
      WHERE threads.thread_id=messages.thread_id
      and nt.threadID=threads.thread_id
      AND messages.user_id=$userID
      GROUP BY messages.thread_id) as t
inner join messages
on t.thread_id = messages.thread_id 
group by t.thread_id
order by date DESC
```

And the problem with this query is that it returns what I need, but the message that is returned per each thread is the first message of the thread, not the last ("most recent") message. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the last entries using GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811750/get-the-last-entries-using-group-by)